# Jupyter Notebook Doesn't Ever Finish Running Script When time.sleep() Introduced

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, yfinance

I'd like this script to show me the dataframe and then generate a new one w/ the latest data 1 min later. Problem is when I run this script in Jupyter notebook, it doesn't ever complete the first iteration of this. This code works in idle and a few other IDEs I've tested. Can't really find anything similar to this issue online. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

```
while True:
 hist = data.history(period='1d',interval='1m')
 hist.drop(['Volume', 'Dividends', 'Stock Splits'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
 hist['Difference'] = hist.Close - hist.Open
 hist.dropna(inplace=True) # drop rows with N/A in columns
 hist['Difference'].mean()
 hist.set_index(hist.index, inplace = True)
 hist['MA5'] = hist.Close.rolling(5).mean()
 hist['MA25'] = hist.Close.rolling(25).mean()
 hist.dropna(inplace=True)
 hist
 time.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Jupyter automatically prints out the last value. However, with a `while True`, there is no "last value". You'll have to use `print` manually

For example:

```
import time
for i in (1, 2, 3):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you! That worked and I learned something new.